# Add element in post array using php

Tags: php, arrays, push

I have a $_POST array and I would like to add a key at the very end.

So what I am doing is,

```
array_push($_POST['ques_15'] , '');
```

it works but I am getting a warning

```
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

How can I remove this warning without turning off display errors.

Comment: `$_POST['ques_15'] = '';`

Comment: just `$_post` don't give index . Then it will consider it as a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you simply want to do:

```
$_POST['ques_15'] = '';
```

It will add at the end of $_POST array value `''` with key `ques_15`

Answer (score 4):

$_POST is an **`associative`**  array.

Both `array_push()`  and the directly providing key:value to your array will work.

Instead of `array_push()` , I would go like this :

```
<?php

$_POST['ques_15'] = '';

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's simple as:

```
$_POST[] = 'value';
```

or

```
$_POST['yourkey'] = 'value'
```

Answer (score 1):

it will be `array_push($_POST , '');`
as `$_POST['key']` is not an array. `$_POST` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

As @billyonecan mentioned in comment simply  using `$_POST['ques_15'] = ''`  can solve your problem ..:)